# How to print the URL's of google in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can we print the URL's which appears in the Google's results in the python in version 2.7?

Here is the code,

```
domain = sys.argv[1];
print domain;
test = []

test.append("aa")    
mainURL = "http://google.com/?q=";

finalurl = mainURL + test[0]


req = requests.get(finalurl)
```

**How can I print the URL's after firing up the request.get(finalurl)?**

Comment: Have a look at the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

Comment: Check this, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/

Comment: You need to parse the results. Often, people do this with a library called [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). But you will need to understand a bit about HTML, and read at least the quickstart for the library, in order to write this code.

Comment: @RahulKP I did the same, what when I import the google module it says no module found. Even I installed it with pip install <library>

Comment: Also, your URL is wrong, it's "google.com/search?q="

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got it. Beautiful soap is gonna help me. And I really don't care about my devote question. I am actually getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be:

```
r = requests.get("url");
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("cite")
```

You can look at the website's source code (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, or dev-tools/Inspector and find the tags/class/id where your data is. I see e.g.: `<cite class="iUh30">link...`)

Now the problem is here, if you look at, the output of:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Then you see, they do not just give you back plain-text, but generate it with JS.

- You could have a look at other search engines responses
- Dig deeper into Js code execution from python (maybe other libs etc?)
- Please, also think about, that some would not consider parsing out data from other websites programatically and in big amount without permission legit. But I have no idea what google's policy is regarding this.
- [requests advanced usage](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)
- [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

=======
EDIT:
@Rahul's link is the fastest solution to OP.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/